# Do we need to apply for a transit visa in advance for Dublin (DUB), Ireland?

Tags: transit-visas, ireland

This is my first-time travel through Dublin (DUB), Ireland. During my trip, it says I have to change planes at Dublin (DUB). Connection time is around 4 hours. But still, it says I need a transit visa.

In the [official Irish Visas site](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/fees), my country is listed under the nationalities exempt from visa fees.

So my questions
are:

1. Do I need to have my transit visa before I start my journey? Or can I apply at the airport itself? (I haven't applied for a transit visa before so please excuse if this is a stupid question)
2. Since my country is listed under the nationalities exempt from visa fees, should I be able to get a transit visa for free?

Has anyone experienced a similar situation before?

Comment: What nationality are you?  The answer will vary depending on your nationality...

Comment: Being exempt from visa _fees_ is not the same as being exempt from the visa requirement itself. It just means you don't have to _pay_ for applying for a visa -- but if you need one you still have to _apply_.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to have my transit visa applied before I start my journey? Or can I apply from the airport itself?

You must have the visa before you begin your journey.

> It certainly seems that way, although the page also notes that there may be an additional consular fee on top of the visa fee.  So you might have to pay the consular fee.